# VBA Excel auto select space delimited data range for formula use

Tags: vba, excel

Fairly new to programming. I have data in excel that is delimited by an empty cell at the top and bottom of each group 
`(example, A1=empty, A2=a number, A3= a number, A4= a number, A5=Empty, A6=a number, A7=a number, A8=Empty)` This pattern repeats into the thousands of rows.

I would like to use vba to take the sum of the numbers between each set of empty cells and place that value 6 cells to the right of the top-most empty cell for each group.

I would do this by hand, but there is a TON of data.  It needs to continue until it reaches 2 empty cells in a row(signifies end of data). Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Tyler, since you didn't mention or include an specific issue or code, I can only give suggestions where you can somehow derive a possible solution. If your data is as uniform as you've describe, you can do it manually by formula (on the first space you need to put your value to). Then autofill the formula all the way down. Copy and paste it as values. Then filter your data and select all non blanks, and delete the sum of those. That will give you what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt mean that the number of data points per group was consistent. I just meant the empty cells above and below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example that should help:

```
Sub SumGroups()
    Dim i As Long ' rows counter
    Dim j As Long ' first row of current group, having empty cell
    Dim s As Double ' summ
    i = 1 ' start row
    Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = "" ' loop to first group begin
        i = i + 1 ' next row
    Loop
    j = i ' new group start
    s = 0
    Do
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then ' empty cell found
            If j = i - 1 Then Exit Do ' finish if previous cell is also empty
            Cells(j, 2).Value = s ' put calculated summ at the top of the group
            j = i ' new group start
            s = 0
        Else  ' value cell found
            s = s + Cells(i, 1).Value ' add each value in the group
        End If
        i = i + 1 ' next row
    Loop
End Sub
```